# How to fix the 404 error in Strapi routes pages?

Tags: strapi

I am using the **Strapi v3.0.0-beta.18.7** when I am trying to open the **routes pages** with the json, I see **404 error**.

> I had this error previously. 
>   I solved it just started the new empty project and copied the */config,* */api,* */components* directories in the
>   new project. But after some time it starts to show **404 again**.

Starting a new project each time when Strapi through 404 error doesn't sound like a good solution.

Does anyone have an idea why does this error occur and how to fix or prevent it?

Comment: Hello, what is the exact route that gave you a 404 error?

Comment: @JimLAURIE, 
all of them gives that error.



For example:

`{
  "routes": [
  {
      "method": "GET",
      "path": "/TEST_NAME",
      "handler": "TEST-NAME.find",
      "config": {
        "policies": []
      }
    },
...
]
}  `

Comment: Hum content type with a `-` or `_` that looks weird. Please can you make sure the name is lower of camelCase please.